# What is "YEEZY DID KEEZY"

Tags: meaning

On a episode of SUBURGATORY, someone said I'LL DO A YEEZY DID KEEZY, therefore she made a song video.
You can see the description 
https://youtu.be/EV39aC4tpzw
I was trying to search the meaning and none results, not even dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

The correct quote from the episode Krampus was, "I'll do like Yeezy did Keezy."

Yeezy is a [silly nickname for Kanye West](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=yeezy). From the context, I presume Keezy means Kim Kardashian.

So it means, "I'll write a song to win over Carmen, just like Kanye West did for Kim Kardashian."